# How can I convert custom emojis to an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to convert all emojis in a message to an array. I've tried this:

```
const myArray = message.attachments.array();
```

and this:

```
const myArray = Array.from(message.attachments);
```

but they both return: `[]`

Comment: Make sure the message has an attachment. (Example: image). Note: URL images are not counted as attachments.

Comment: Would a custom emoji count as an attachment? If not, how would I make it into an array?

Comment: No, custom emojis aren't counted as attachments either. You'll need to scan the message content for emojis and add them to an array manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the message contains emojis with regular expression (regex).
For example:

```js
let array = [],
    rgx = /(:)/g, // This will check for the emoji syntax e.g. :mali_borivoje:
    item;

while(item = rgx.exec()) {
    array.push(item[1]);
    array.join(' ');
}
```

Note: This code is purely for showcase purpose, it may not work out of the box for you. You may update it accordingly to your code base and intentions.